# How to map a range of logarithmically increasing values in Octave?

Tags: logging, mapping, octave

I measured the response of a circuit by sweeping a range of frequencies (30Hz to 8000Hz) across it in a 10s logarithmic sweep. The device I used to make measurements of the response of the circuit gives me amplitude and the time that amplitude was sampled, from 0s to 10s. I would like to plot the data in Octave as amplitude versus frequency, with frequency on a log scale.

However, the closest function I can find that I could use to even create a simple log range only extends to ranges starting with 10^x, rather some arbitrary value (in this case 30 - 8000). How can I accomplish this mapping in Octave?

Comment: The function you found is `logspace`. Use limits `log10(30)` and `log10(8000)`.

Comment: Thank you - the following is my full solution: x2 = logspace(log10(30),log10(8000),length(x));

Comment: also of interest would be the `semilogx` function